# issues with using partial from another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently working on Rails 2.3.5. I have a model Blog and Blog has_many comments. In my comment for displaying the comment

```
            views/comments/_comment.html.erb
    <li class="depth-1">
        <div class="comment-info">
            <cite>
              <a href="index.html"><%= comment.user.name %></a> Says: <br>
              <span class="comment-data"><a title="" href="#"><%=  comment.created_at.stftime('%B %d, %Y  at %I:%M %p')%></a></span>
            </cite>
        </div>

        <div class="comment-text">
            <p><%= comment.content %></p>

            <div class="reply">
              <a href="index.html" class="comment-reply-link" rel="nofollow">Comment</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
```

this partial is called both from blogs/show.html.erb and comments/create.rjs. The partial is called from the show view as such

```
    <%= render :partial=>'comments/comment', @collection => @blog.comments %>
```

but when i access my link localhost:3000/blogs/6, i get the following error

```
    NoMethodError in Blogs#show
    Showing app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb where line #6 raised:
    undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
    Extracted source (around line #6):

    3: 
    4:   <div class="comment-info">
    5:     <cite>
    6:       <a href="index.html"><%= comment.user.name %></a> Says: <br>
    7:       <span class="comment-data"><a title="" href="#comment-63"><%=  comment.created_at.stftime('%B %d, %Y  at %I:%M %p')%></a></span>
    8:     </cite>
    9:   </div>

    Trace of template inclusion: app/views/blogs/show.html.erb
```

but the user attribute is well defined and the name exists for all users.

Comment: what is relation between user and comments

Comment: user has_many comments and comment belongs_to user

Comment: while saving the comment r you attaching the id of user to comment or not ?

Comment: try to print all comment.user_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You entered `@` instead of colon `:` in your partial, check the [Partials documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Partials.html).

The correct format is:

```
<%= render :partial=>'comments/comment', :collection => @blog.comments %>
```